# is there any core function find_by_controller in ruby on rails framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

My first project as a software engineer is adding features to an existing ruby on rails crm application. I had to add functionality for sending an automated email, for which I just copied and pasted from another place in the program, where this was happening. The trouble is that now I want to modify it. Here's the code that does it?

```
recipient = session[:registration][:email]
subject = ManagedContent.get_email_subject("checkout", session[:registration][:id])
message = ManagedContent.find_by_controller("checkout").content_text
RegistrationConfirmationMailer.deliver_registration_message(recipient, subject, message, @registration_transaction.registration.id, render_to_string(:template => "registration_invoices/show.haml", :layout => 'none', :locals => {:registration => @registration_transaction.registration, :event => @registration_transaction.registration.event}) )
```

From what I gather from this that the message to be sent is being crafted in third line by calling `find_by_controller()` function. However, I can't find that function either in ManagedContent model or controller. I have even done a grep search of the entire workspace for this project, I didn't find any definition. Googling too didn't return anything that I could make sense of. Where can I look for this method definition as I need to make a little modification in the `message`

Thank you!

Comment: What is you ManagedContent Object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find_by_(field) is an ActiveRecord construction letting you find a record based on the value of a field.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html (especially section 14 on Dynamic Finders).

So you should look for a "controller" column in your managed_content table.  Based on the code you copied, there is a row in that table with a value "checkout" for the controller column.  In that same row, the value for the "content_text" field is the value you want to change.

PS:  Congrats on your first software gig.  Enjoy it while still untainted. :)

Comment: Wonderful! - thank you for such an answer! Finally I learn that grep is not the answer to all code reading...

Answer (score 1):

If your ManagedContent is a ActiveRecord class, doing `find_by_controller` generates an SQL request on your ManagedContent table to do a restriction on `controller` columns.

All is in `dynamic finder` documentation

Comment: Indeed my ManagedContent is an ActiveRecord class. Let me check out the documentation you speak of :)